# my setTimeout doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout

this is the code:

```
var stripeAnimation = function() {

var streetDivWidth = $('.street_name').width();
var streetFull = $('.street_name .street_name_text');

for(var i=0; i<streetFull.length; i++) {
    var item = $(streetFull[i]);
    var widthFull = item.width();
    var remainder = widthFull - streetDivWidth;
    var animationSpeed = widthFull * 5;
    var summary = streetDivWidth - widthFull;
    if(summary < 0) {
        item.children('.gradient_span').addClass('gradient');
        infinite();
        setTimeout(infinite, 1000);
    }

}
function infinite() {
    item.animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + remainder + 'px'
    }, animationSpeed).animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, widthFull).delay(1000);
}

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    stripeAnimation();
});
```

It looks like it should loop the animation over and over in a delay of 1000ms - "setTimeout(infinite, 1000);". but it doesn't. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop, then you need to use setInterval()

```
setInterval(infinite, 10000);
```

then

```
function infinite() {
    item.animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + remainder + 'px'
    }, animationSpeed).animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, widthFull);
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using setInterval for animations, it could cause an uneven animation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/twTLz/2/ here, i have no idea why does it work only for the last span block.(((

Answer (score 0):

Remainder variable is local and u are using it as like global function. should declare it globally.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will call your function only once but, as Arun P said, you have the choice of using `setInterval`, only it isn't recommended for animation. The problem with setInterval is that the delay interval you specify is the minimum time until it will be called but not a promise it will be called when that interval is over.

An example will be, if you set an interval of 300 milliseconds but the queue was held up by other operations (UI or other JS operations) for, let's say, 600 milliseconds your function will be called twice, one after the other with no delay, which will make your animation uneven. You can't ensure a timeout will be called at exactly your interval, only no less than that interval.

A better approach would be to make your first initial call with a setTimeout, as you have done, and again at the end of the `infinite()` function call `setTimeout(infinite, 1000)` again.

With all that said, if it's applicable, the best way to do animations is the requestAnimationFrame method, you can look into it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Hi! Thank You. But I changed the method, it still works in the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/twTLz/9/

Comment: It does loop, What do you mean by "still works in the same way"? what doesn't it do right?

Comment: It looks good, I see you have used requestAnimationFrame and also call it at the infinite function. As this is what I suggested I'd appreciate it if you can accept my answer as the correct answer for this question and vote it up

Comment: Thanks a lot! But sorry - I can't vote your answer up because I have low reputation. I will when I reach some.